# umbraco content tree fails to load after formulate install

Tags: umbraco

I recently installed formulate form builder on my umbraco 7.3.0 site and now the content tree fails to load!

How do I revert the site to its previous state if I cant access the menus, see here:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check the log to see what it says? It's usually in App_Data/Logs.

Comment: As mentioned by @JannikAnker, please check log file and post them here for feedback.